# Keberos clock skrew, although the clocks are synchronized

Tags: backup, kerberos, vmware-vcenter

We have an issue during a backup (run every night).
This backup is managed by Veeam Backup&Replication : copy 7 virtual machines from one VMware ESXi host.
This host is linked to a vCenter server.
This vCenter server is joined to a active directory domain.
Veeam B&R uses an account which have enough rights in vCenter.

Those backups run at 9pm, 10pm and 11pm, with the same account, from the same Veeam server, to the same vCenter server.

The first 2 backups run successfully, but the last one end with errors. This 3rd backup copies 7 virtual machines. The first 4 are copied but the last 3 aren't. The error is login error (bad user or password).

Veeam one (esx and veeam B&R monitor) report login issue about 11pm.

Looking in vmware (vSphere 5.1.0) event log, we see the same things.

Looking in vCenter (windows server 2008 R2) security event log, we see nothing.

Looking in main domain controller (windows server 2003 R2) security event log, we see lot of failures :

- 9pm and 10pm : get error 675 (kerberos pre-authenthicate 0x19 = pre-authentication required) followed by success 672.
- at 11:02pm : get error 675 (kerberos pre-authenticate 0x25 = clock skrew) followed by success 672 too.
- at 11:07pm : get error 673 (kerberos ticket failure code 0x25) not followed by success.

Those backups are configured since 2 weeks. We got a first failure monday and second wednesday (but tuesday was ok).

We don't know if this problem is relative to vmware, to veeam or to kerberos.

All my servers are sync:

```
PS C:\Users\cedric> $t = ("veeamone","veeamserver","vcenterserver5","theorix","controlix","veeamproxy1","veeamproxy2")

PS C:\Users\cedric> $t |%{ net time \\$_ | Select-String -Pattern "en cours" }
L'heure en cours sur \\veeamone est 17/04/2014 10:41:08
L'heure en cours sur \\veeamserver est 17/04/2014 10:41:08
L'heure en cours sur \\vcenterserver5 est 17/04/2014 10:41:08
L'heure en cours sur \\theorix est 17/04/2014 10:41:08
L'heure en cours sur \\controlix est 17/04/2014 10:41:08
L'heure en cours sur \\veeamproxy1 est 17/04/2014 10:41:09
L'heure en cours sur \\veeamproxy2 est 17/04/2014 10:41:09
```

Please help me ! (i hope my frenglish is understandable)